# Issue making HTTPS connection using Edge(with Cordova), signalr and OWIN self host

Tags: cordova, ssl, https, signalr, microsoft-edge

Long time reader, first time poster...

TL:DR Summary:

We have a windows service running SignalR server on OWIN self host.
We have a Cordova application running SingalR JS client.
Everything works fine when we connect via HTTP.

However when we switch to using HTTPS with a self signed certificate we get the generic SignalR message "Error During Negotiation". There is no more detail to the error message. It still works fine on Chrome.

Is there an issue with Edge and SignalR using self-signed certificates?

--

Server Side Detail:

We are running the server on an on-site embedded windows 8 server which is limited to .NET framework 4.5. We are using Microsoft.Owin v2.1.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (& .SelfHost) v2.4.0. Server has TLS1.1 enabled.

URLACL reservation has been made on the server for our SSL port, the certificate has been assigned to that port.

This has been tried with IIS & openSSL self signed certificates. The certificates have been moved into the trusted root certficiates.

We have also tried using NGINX as a proxy server. Same results.

Client Detail:

Use case is that client and server are on the same network and we cannot guarantee that either have internet access.

We are using Cordova to make a cross platform application. This is using the SignalR JavaScript client. It all works fine over HTTP. Chrome browser and android app (which leverages the Chrome browser as the front end) works fine with HTTPS. Edge browser and windows app (which leverages edge browser as the front end) does not work over HTTPS.

Interestingly, signalr produces an auto-generated hubs js page which I can successfully access via HTTPS through either Chrome or Edge browser using the self signed certificate.

Does anyone have any hints as to what I'm doing wrong or what could be causing this issue in Edge?

Comment: I suggest you could try to compare the https request in Edge and Chrome browser, and check whether they are contains different. Besides, you could also try to [Enable SignalR Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#phone) to check the diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0):

In Summary, this was abandoned in favour of using a Cordova plugin to access native code to implement a TCP socket. This way we were able to handle certificates with more control.